# Headlight problem on 2013 silverado

Tags: chevrolet, headlight, silverado

Ok  passenger  low beam don't work put new headlight in and checked fuses brights work ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a broken circuit somewhere, so check that the passenger headlight circuit has voltage all the way from battery to the light. Typically headlights are switched on by a relay. Since only one of your lights is out, it's likely either the relay itself or somewhere after that.

Probably the headlight switch turns on both relays, so the wire probably splits somewhere after the switch and before the relays. You could have a problem in that wire section as well.

Comment: In general, GM's of this generation use individual fuses for L/R Hi/Lo lights. The light switch and high beam switch send a signal to the BCM which grounds the Hi/Lo relay terminal 86. The relays energize said fuses.